# Keep lines containing "list of different words" like pattern

Tags: sed

How can I keep all lines matching all those words
`toto` OR `titi` OR `clic` OR `SOMETHING` and delete any other lines?

If I do `sed '/toto/ p ' file` I cannot select `titi` for example.

What I am looking for is something similar to a Perl Regular expression as
`^ (word1|word2|word3|andsoon).*`. However, I need it for `sed` because it will be integrated into a bigger `sed` script.

The goal is to keep all lines starting with `word` where `word` is any word from a set of words.

Comment: How is your larger `sed` script called? If it is called just as `sed`, then the task at hand would be to delete all lines that do not match to corresponding expressions, if it is called as `sed -n` you actually have to select the lines you are interested in. But my overall suggestion would be set your first `awk` rule to delete the lines that do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here depends a bit on how your master script is called. Imagine you have a file with the following content:

```
foo
car
bar
```

and you are interested in the lines matching "foo" and "bar", then you can do:

```
sed '/foo\|bar/!d'
sed -n '/foo\|bar/!d;p'
sed -n '/foo\|bar/p'
```

all these will output:

```
foo
bar
```

If you would just do:

```
sed '/foo\|bar/p'
```

you actually duplicate the lines.

```
foo
foo
car
bar
bar
```

As you see, there is a bit of different handling depending on the usage of the `-n` flag.

> **`-n, --quiet, --silent`** suppress automatic printing of pattern space
>
> **<sub>source: `man sed`</sub>**

In general, my suggestion is to **delete** the lines you don't need at the beginning of your `sed` script.

Comment: nearly that ... so I adapted it as sed -i -E '/^(word1.*|word2|word3.*|etc.)$/ !d'  thanks

Comment: @francoisP don't forget to escape your `|` and brackets, it is `/^\(word1\|word2\|word3\|...\).*$/!d`